# Any way to fix train bridge glitches?

Tags: the-saboteur

I don't know what combination of events caused the train bridge to glitch, but so far I've destroyed three of them and I have two left (that I know of). The problem I'm having is I get part way through planting the explosive and it stops giving me the option to plant explosives at the rest of the markers.

**Bridge A:**

- The first time I attempted this one I planted all four explosives on the arches of the bridge, but it wouldn't give me the option to plant the last one on the tracks. I had accidentally left the restricted area briefly and re-entered, and it gave me the last marker again. Then I died and had to try again.
- The second time I attempted, it let me plant two of the explosives on the arches and the other two arches wouldn't give me the option to plant them anymore.
- I tried leaving and coming back which reset the explosives. I was again able to place all four explosives on the arches of the bridge, but wasn't able to place the final one on the tracks (same as first try). I did not leave the restricted area this time, though.

**Bridge B:**

- I've only attempted this one once. But it let me plant three explosives on the arches and only one of the markers isn't giving me the option to plant explosives.

---

Is there something huge that I'm missing here? Do I have to wait longer between bridges? I've had three different scenarios for how it ended up explosives-wise so I'm a bit confused as to what the heck is causing this glitch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A bit confusing what happened with odd numbers. You do have to buy the Bridge Killer packs from a weapons dealer (you can buy two packs of five for a total of ten, needing five per bridge). As for unglitching the bridges, I just kept playing for a while and eventually the bridges got rebuilt and I was able to redo them to complete the perk. They continue getting rebuilt constantly so if it glitches don't worry, it'll fix itself at some point (you could probably exit the game and reload it as well).